# Set the value of drop down list - with known options - with particular custom attribute value

Tags: jquery

I have this select element

```
<select class="zip_plus_master" data-stype='proof'></select>
```

The  values are loaded from a database, where the ID's of these values is the value of the attribute "data-zipid" for all options. An example option is like this:

```
<option data-zipid='34'>95628-1092</option>
```

How can I have an option with a certain data-zipid attribute value selected?

After parsing, the value of "data-zipid" for all options is currentJSONset.value

I've tried this:

```
$('.zip_plus_master[data-stype=proof] option:selected').attr('data-zipid', currentJSONset.value);
```

Comment: you want an option wiith certain data-zipid as selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the option with `data-zipid="34"`:

```
$('select.zip_plus_master[data-stype=proof] option[data-zipid="34"]').attr('selected', 'selected')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You just saved me lots of time